# Return child class from parent

Tags: php, class, oop, design-patterns

Hoping someone can help me.

I want a 'base/parent' class that holds the common functionality between two child classes, but I also want the constructor of the base/parent to decide which child class to use - so I can simply create an instance of ParentClass, and use ParentClass->method(); but what it is actually doing is deciding which child to use and creating an instance of that child.

I thought the way to do this would be to return new ChildClass(); in the constructor, but then get_class() returns the ParentClass in the 'base/shared' methods.

A little example (My class is more complex than this, so it may look odd that I for example am not just calling the child class directly):

```
class ParentClass {
  private $aVariable;
  public function __construct( $aVariable ) {
    $this->aVariable = $aVariable;
    if ($this->aVariable == 'a') {
      return new ChildClassA();
    else {
      return new ChildClassB();
    }
  }

  public function sharedMethod() {
    echo $this->childClassVariable;
  }
}

class ChildClassA extends ParentClass {
    protected $childClassVariable;
    function __construct() {
        $this->childClassVariable = 'Test';
    }
}

class ChildClassB extends ParentClass {
    protected $childClassVariable;
    function __construct() {
        $this->childClassVariable = 'Test2';
    }
}
```

I want to:

```
$ParentClass = new ParentClass('a');
echo $ParentClass->sharedMethod();
```

And expect the output to be 'Test'.

It also also my intention that a child class would have their own methods and I can use $ParentClass->nonShareMethod() to call them. So ParentClass is both acting as a 'proxy' and as a 'base'.

Comment: No matter what you will do in your `__construct()` (unless raise an exception or terminate script) - it will return _instance of class to which it belongs_ (to be more precise, not _return_ - but _instantiate_ inside context where it was called via `new`, for example). So your conditional return makes no sense

Comment: There are typo errors on your code. extends ParentClass()  instead write ParentClass,  and if ($this->aVariable == 'a') { is missing breacket.

Comment: You might be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Sorry for the miss-spellings, it was written as pretty much pseudo-code using my code as a reference rather than a working example. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks - I think the Factory Method Pattern is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute the methods of the `child` class from the `parent` class !

Comment: Is there any way to achieve what it is I want? I want a base class with common functionality with children that can over-ride methods. But I want a single access point, so something that can decide which class it is I need and will create an instance of that class for me to use.